# A Simple Regular Expression to ex

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression to match a text files content.

Here as you can see, it only matches one line of the text

I need to match all three lines. like this.

and it shouldn't match any other occurrence of 'list' in the text unless it ends with {..}.

any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question to include the regex you tried, on top of providing the regex101 link: questions shouldn't depend on external resources.

Comment: `following regular expression`...where is the expression??? or is it not showing on my IE for some reason!!??

Comment: And wich three lines?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something in this spirit, adapt at your convenience.

```
(?m)^(?:list.*,\s*)*list.*,?\s*{[^}]*}

(?m)            # multiline flag (^ matches begin of line, not of string)
^               # beginning of line
(?:             # non captring group
    list.*,\s*  # list then anything then a mandatory comma, then whitespaces (possibly newline)
)*              # zero or more times
list.*,?\s*     # at least one list-line, ending or not with a comma
{[^}]*}         # what's inside the brackets
```

Using a separate non capturing group instead of `(?:list.*,?\s*)+` makes sure that multiple `list` lines are separated by commas.

See [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/kH4oM8)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
/^list.*?(?:,|\{\.\.\})$/gsim
```

http://regex101.com/r/zK5bP0

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
((?:list*)(?:\:{1,2})\s*[\w\W]*[^\,]*?)
```